# How to join the left end of an arrow with a line?

Tags: xy-pic

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
A\ar@{-} [rr]  & & D\ar @{-}[r] & E\\
 L\ar @{-}[rrr]              &         &         & M \\
P\ar[rrr]\ar[uu]  & R\ar[ruu] & S & T\ar @{-}[uu]
}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following diagram :

[image: Commutative diagram]

But, I would like to produce the diagram below :

[image: Adjusted diagram]

How can I do this using  the package `xypic`?

Comment: The line RP not shown here. The line RP will remain in the final diagram.

Comment: Would you be willing to use another package?

Comment: If this package fails to do this, tell me another.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an xypic version of your second diagram.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}

\begin{xy}<1cm,0cm>:
  (0,0)="P"; (0,2)="A" **@{-};
  (4,2)="E" **@{-}; (4,0)="T" **@{-}; "P" **@{-},
  (0,1)="L"; (4,1)="M" **@{-},
  (1.3,0)="R"; "R"+(0,0.1) **@{-},
  (3,0)="S"; "S"+(0,0.1) **@{-},
  (2.6,2)="D"; "D"-(0,0.1) **@{-},
  (2.2,0) *{>},
  "P"-(0.2,0.2)*{P},
  "L"-(0.2,0)*{L},
  "A"+(-0.2,0.2)*{A},
  "D"+(0,0.2)*{D},
  "E"+(0.2,0.2)*{E},
  "M"+(0.2,0)*[r]{M},
  "T"+(0.2,-0.2)*{T},
  "S"-(0,0.2)*{S},
  "R"-(0,0.2)*{R}
\end{xy}

\end{document}
```

The first collection of commands draws the lines and provides some reference names for the points.  The second collection prints the arrow and the labels.  See the [Reference Manual of xypic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic) (or `texdoc xyrefer` on your computer) for more details.  This is more helpful than the User Guide (`texdoc xypic`), which is mostly directed towards creation of so-called "commutative diagrams".

Note the syntax carefully.  The line drawing operation `**@{-}` uses the last two points on a stack; it is followed by `;` when we want to continue on from the last point, but by `,` when we need to start a completely new operation.

I guess you were also asking how to add arrows to this diagram, presumably from `R` to `D`, rather than `R` to `P` in the comment.  One way would be

```
"R"; "D" **@{-} ?(.7)*\dir{>}
```

which places the arrow head `.7` of the distance from `R` to `D`.  A comparable construction could be used for the arrow on the bottom line.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know `xy` well, but here's one possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
% coordinates for the points
\coordinate (A) ;
\coordinate[right = 2cm of A] (D) ;
\coordinate[right = of D] (E) ;
\coordinate[below = of A] (L) ;
\coordinate[below = of L] (P) ;
\coordinate[right = of P] (R) ;
\coordinate[right = 1.3cm of R] (S) ;
\coordinate[below = of E] (M);
\coordinate[below = of M] (T);
% join some points with straight line segments
\draw (R) -- (P) -- (L) -- (A) -- (D) -- (E) -- (M) -- (T) -- (S);
\draw (L) -- (M);
% draw the segment from R to S with arrow in the middle
\draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}] (R) -- (S);
% draw tick-marks at R,S and D
\draw (R) -- +(0,3pt);
\draw (S) -- +(0,3pt);
\draw (D) -- +(0,-3pt);
% place the labels
\foreach \coor/\posi in {R/below,P/below left,L/left,A/above left,D/above,E/above right,M/right,T/below right,S/below}
  \node[\posi] at (\coor) {\coor};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about 'tikzpicture' could you please give me some reference book where I can get details esily  about this package? Thank you.

Comment: @SoumitraSen My answer contains the link to the package in CTAN; following this link you'll see another ones; amongst them, one to the [`PGF manual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) and the other, to a [`Minimal introduction to TikZ`](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) (I provided the links here, for your commodity). There's also TeXample.net with a [`gallery of examples`](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).